# How do I change symbol type colors on D3js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, colors, force-layout

I want to change colors of the symbol types on my D3 code? I am not sure how to make my `var color = d3.scale.linear()` work. I am trying to randomize D3 symbol types but want to differentiate them by colors.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var w = 1260, //define the canvas
    h = 500,
    nodes = [], //nodes are shapes
    node; //return node..data

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain ([0, h])
    .range ([0, w]);

//creating canvas with svg property
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

//https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#force
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([]) //links are between nodes
    .size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function(d) {
  canvas.selectAll("path")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});

setInterval(function(){

  // Add a new random shape.
  nodes.push({
    type: d3.svg.symbolTypes[~~(Math.random() * d3.svg.symbolTypes.length)], //pushing symbol types
    size: Math.random() * 300 + 100 //randomize size
  });

  // Restart the layout.
  force.start();

  canvas.selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
      .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
        .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
        .style("fill", "#69d3bf")
        .style("stroke", "#253544")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .call(force.drag);
}, 10); //1000 is time 

</script>
```

Comment: When asking these types of questions, you might want to consider opening up a jsfiddle (or something similar) for it.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your example, just slightly modified to be a runnable code snippet:

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var nodes = [];

//https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#force
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links([]) //links are between nodes
  .size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});

setInterval(function() {

  // Add a new random shape.
  nodes.push({
    type: d3.svg.symbolTypes[~~(Math.random() * d3.svg.symbolTypes.length)], //pushing symbol types
    size: Math.random() * 300 + 100 //randomize size
  });

  // Restart the layout.
  force.start();

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
      .size(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .type(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      }))
    .style("fill", "#69d3bf")
    .style("stroke", "#253544")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .call(force.drag);

}, 3000); //1000 is time
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Note that there are only six symbols supported.

I am going to present two solutions, to get you started. You can adjust them to suit your needs, and, of course, with the help of documentation.

### First solution

Key portions of the code:

```
.style("fill",  function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  var symbolIndex = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<d3.svg.symbolTypes.length; i++){
    if(d.type == d3.svg.symbolTypes[i])
      symbolIndex=i;
  };
  return color(symbolIndex);
})
```

`color` is defined as linear scale from yellow to violet:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain ([0, d3.svg.symbolTypes.length-1])
    .range (["yellow", "violet"]);
```

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var nodes = [];
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain ([0, d3.svg.symbolTypes.length-1])
    .range (["yellow", "violet"]);

//https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#force
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links([]) //links are between nodes
  .size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});

setInterval(function() {

  // Add a new random shape.
  nodes.push({
    type: d3.svg.symbolTypes[~~(Math.random() * d3.svg.symbolTypes.length)], //pushing symbol types
    size: Math.random() * 300 + 100 //randomize size
  });

  // Restart the layout.
  force.start();

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
      .size(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .type(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      }))
    .style("fill",  function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      var symbolIndex = 0;
      for(var i=0; i<d3.svg.symbolTypes.length; i++){
        if(d.type == d3.svg.symbolTypes[i])
          symbolIndex=i;
      };
      return color(symbolIndex);
    })
    .style("stroke", "#253544")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .call(force.drag);

}, 3000); //1000 is time
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

### Second solution

If you want to explicitly set color for each symbol, you can use this:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .range (["red", "blue", "green", "tan", "gray", "orange"]);
```

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var nodes = [];
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .range (["red", "blue", "green", "tan", "gray", "orange"]);

//https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#force
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links([]) //links are between nodes
  .size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});

setInterval(function() {

  // Add a new random shape.
  nodes.push({
    type: d3.svg.symbolTypes[~~(Math.random() * d3.svg.symbolTypes.length)], //pushing symbol types
    size: Math.random() * 300 + 100 //randomize size
  });

  // Restart the layout.
  force.start();

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
      .size(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .type(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      }))
    .style("fill",  function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      var symbolIndex = 0;
      for(var i=0; i<d3.svg.symbolTypes.length; i++){
        if(d.type == d3.svg.symbolTypes[i])
          symbolIndex=i;
      };
      return color(symbolIndex);
    })
    .style("stroke", "#253544")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .call(force.drag);

}, 3000); //1000 is time
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]